# Function to check SSL takes too long to load

Tags: php, http, ssl, https

I have a function which checks whether ssl is working fine on a domain or not which I found here.

```
function has_ssl($domain)
{
    $ssl_check = fsockopen('ssl://' . $domain, 443, $errno, $errstr, 1000);
    $res = !!$ssl_check;
    if ($res == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm looking for an alternate function because this one takes too long to load and when I have to check ssl for hundreds of domains, it gives server timeout error as well. If someone can give me an alternative function that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

i'm Glad to help!

First,define a function that gets ssl cert info:

```php
function get_cert_info($domain){
    $context = stream_context_create(['ssl' => [
        'capture_peer_cert' => true,
        'capture_peer_cert_chain' => true,
        ],
    ]);

    $client = stream_socket_client("ssl://".$domain.":443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
    if($client==false) {
        return false;
    }
    $params = stream_context_get_params($client);
    $cert = $params['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate'];
    $cert_info = openssl_x509_parse($cert);
    return $cert_info;
}
```

Then use it to check domians like this:

```php
$domain = 'example.com';
$cert_info = get_cert_info($domain);
$validTo_time_t = $cert_info['validTo_time_t'];
$validTo_time_d = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $validTo_time_t);
if($validTo_time_d>date('Y-m-d H:i:s',now())) echo "true";
else echo "false";
```

Also, i just checked the time in my code.

You can check other infomation like: **cert publisher, cert publish time......**

Hope it works!

Have a good day!

Comment: This works but still takes the same amount of time to load :(

Answer (score 0):

You have way too big timeout, probably 15 seconds is good enough (higher than that means that something is wrong anyway). Also for scalability you need some way of multitasking. I like to use [parallel](https://github.com/krakjoe/parallel) for such tasks.